# How can we evaluate the characteristic polynomial with a matrix as the parameter?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

> For any polynomial p(x) = $a_0+a_1x+· · ·+a_kx^k$
> and any square matrix A, p(A) is defined
> as p(A) = $a_0I + a_1A + · · · + a_kA^k$
> . Show that if v is any eigenvector of A and $χ_A(x)$ is
> the characteristic polynomial of A, then $χ_A(A)v$ = 0, Deduce that if A is diagonalisable
> then $χ_A(A)$ is the zero matrix

I don't get what it means here to apply the characteristic polynomial with the matrix as the parameter. Does it subtract from each term in p(A)?

Comment: What do you mean by "subtract from each term in $p(A)$"? Your $A$ is a square matrix, so you can raise it to integer powers, multiply it by scalars and add the results, so you can evaluate $p$ at $A$.

Comment: yes but what does it mean to evaluate the characteristic polynomial at A? I know what p(A) does but not $χ_A(A)$

Comment: $\chi_A$ is also a polynomial, so you can evaluate it at $A$ just like you did with $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition given for $p$ is just showing you how to treat $\chi_A(A)$. The characteristic polynomial typically takes scalar values and has roots at the eigenvalues of $A$, but now instead of a function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ we treat it as a function $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ where we plug in a matrix and obtain a matrix as a result. The function $p$ is just being used as an example.

Comment: So is there still this notion of A-λI?

Comment: Yes, that's actually where we get the characteristic polynomial from. The characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$ is the determinant of the matrix $A-\lambda I$

Comment: hm but as $χ_A(A)$ is a polynomial in A it's no longer working out det(A−λI), so I'm wondering how $χ_A(A)$ outputs a matrix that relates to det(A−λI).

Comment: I'm not quite sure how what you mean. Let's do an example. Consider the matrix $A$ defined to be
$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Then $A-\lambda I$ is the matrix
$\begin{bmatrix}
2-\lambda & 1\\
-1 & -\lambda
\end{bmatrix}$
and $\det(A-\lambda I)=\lambda^2-2\lambda+1$. This is the characteristic polynomial. It takes real number values and returns real values. However if instead of plugging in real values we input the matrix $A$ we get $A^2-2A+I$ which is the zero matrix.

Comment: ahh i see thank you!

Comment: No problem! Also if you haven't seen it yet it may interest you to do some reading on Cayley-Hamilton Theorem.

Comment: Cool I'll have a look at that thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other post, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial then $p(A)$ is simply plugging in A. It works analogously (but remember to multiply the constant term by the *identity* matrix).

Now to help you with the second part, you need to know about the spectral mapping theorem. It says that $$spec(p(A))=p(spec(A))$$
That is, the eigenvalues of p(A) are the eigenvalues of A, evaluated in the polynomial, i.e. $p(\lambda_1),...,p(\lambda_n)$, where $\lambda$ are eigenvalues of p(A).

Here $p=\chi$, the characteristic polynomial. Then by the spectral mapping theorem you know that the eigenvalues of $\chi(A)=\chi(\lambda_1),...,\chi(\lambda_n)$. But by definition of the characteristic polynomial, these are all 0. So the only eigenvalue of $\chi(A)$ is 0. If A is diagonalizable, it can be written in the form $A=VDV^{-1}$ where $D=diag(\lambda)$ and V are the eigenvectors. Suppose the characteric polynomial of A has the form $a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$. Then

$$\begin{split}\chi(A)&=a_0I+a_1A+...+a_nA^n\\
&=a_0I+a_1VDV^{-1}+...+a_nVD^nV^{-1}\text{ a nice property of diagonalization}\\
&=V(a_0I+a_1D+...+a_nD^n)V^{-1}\\
&=Vdiag(a_0+a_1\lambda_i+...+a_n\lambda_i^n)V^{-1}\text{ by nice property of diagonal matrices}\end{split}$$

But the characteristic polynomial of A evaluated at each of its eigenvectors is 0. Thus this becomes

$$\begin{split}\chi(A)&=V0V^{-1}\\&=0\end{split}$$ the nxn zero matrix.

This proves the second part.

I leave the first part to you.

Comment: We cover spectral theorem next week and so there should be a different proof not involving this. But once I've covered spectral theorem I will look over this.